Problem using csvsimple package to customize a tabular
I got a table table.txtcontaining:
 $nTracks$ | $PT(\Lambda_b)$ | $\eta(\Lambda_b)$ | $Dira(\Lambda_b)$ |
     0     |      0.039      |       0.045       |       0.017       |
     1     |      0.042      |       0.041       |       0.026       |
     2     |      0.048      |       0.027       |       0.021       |
     3     |      0.039      |       0.024       |       0.023       |
     4     |      0.022      |       0.041       |       0.041       |

with help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643076/273534
I made a standard tabular like this:

I'd like to add a vertical separator after the 1st column with below script:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{table.txt}
 \textit{nTracks} | $PT(\Lambda_b)$ | $\eta(\Lambda_b)$ | \textit{Dira}$(\Lambda_b)$ |
     0     |      0.039      |       0.045       |       0.017       |
     1     |      0.042      |       0.041       |       0.026       |
     2     |      0.048      |       0.027       |       0.021       |
     3     |      0.039      |       0.024       |       0.023       |
     4     |      0.022      |       0.041       |       0.041       |
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
                \csvreader[
                  tabular=r|rrr,
                  separator=pipe,
                  no head,
                  before first line=\\\toprule,
                  late after first line=\\\midrule,
                  late after last line=\\\bottomrule
                ]{table.txt}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii &\csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

However, this went wrong that an extra vertical separator above toprule:

I read the official document on csvsimple-13 package only to be more confused.
How can I get a tabular with a vertical separator after the 1st column?

never use vertical rules with booktabs tables. the package makes vertical rules unusable by design, see its documentation.

your extra line at the top is presumably from before first line=\\\toprule  as you have an \\  at the start.

Instead of using a \midrule, you could use two \cmidrule. This would give you a much nicer separation between rules than a vertical line.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Thanks for your timely help. I modified it to be compliable.
Btw, I understand that the extra line comes from before first line=\\\toprule but don't know how to solve it.
Simply remove the toprule, I got a two-horizontal-line table that looks good. But I still wonder if there is a better way to get exactly what I need.

With vertical lines it works when you use table head = \toprule instead of before first line. However, it does not look good with booktabs, so if you want a vertical line (which, contrary to some opinions, is perfectly valid) it is better to use a regular table with \hline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \csvreader[
          tabular=r|rrr,
          separator=pipe,
          no head,
          table head = \toprule,
          late after first line=\\\midrule,
          late after last line=\\\bottomrule
        ]{tableout.txt}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii &\csvcoliv}
        \caption{Table with booktabs}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
     \csvreader[
       tabular=r|rrr,
       separator=pipe,
       no head,
       table head = \hline,
       late after first line=\\\hline,
       late after last line=\\\hline
     ]{tableout.txt}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii &\csvcoliv}
     \caption{Regular table}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}



If you like the increased line width of \toprule and \bottomrule then you can use them combined with a value of 0 for the rulesep and a bit of array stretch, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399741/:
\begin{table}[h]
        \aboverulesep=0ex
        \belowrulesep=0ex
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
 
        \centering
        \csvreader[
          tabular=r|rrr,
          separator=pipe,
          no head,
          table head = \toprule,
          late after first line=\\\midrule,
          late after last line=\\\bottomrule
        ]{tableout.txt}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii &\csvcoliv}
        \caption{Booktabs with reduced line height}
    \end{table}



Exactly what I need! Thanks a lot. When dealing with this problem myself, I tried to set table head = \toprule but remove no head and this went wrong. It's interesting that this function can assign table head and no head at the same time.

@RedQuark no head just means that the header line does not come from the csv, i.e., that the first line is a data line. It doesn't mean that there is no header - indeed the idea is to provide your own header in the options because the csv does not have the information. In your case it is a bit of a hybrid situation, as there is a header in the csv but you treat it as a data row.

Instead of a vertical line, you could use \cmidrules to separate the first column from the rest:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{table.txt}
 \textit{nTracks} | $PT(\Lambda_b)$ | $\eta(\Lambda_b)$ | \textit{Dira}$(\Lambda_b)$ |
     0     |      0.039      |       0.045       |       0.017       |
     1     |      0.042      |       0.041       |       0.026       |
     2     |      0.048      |       0.027       |       0.021       |
     3     |      0.039      |       0.024       |       0.023       |
     4     |      0.022      |       0.041       |       0.041       |
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
                \csvreader[
                  tabular=rrrr,
                  separator=pipe,
                  no head,
                  before first line=\\\toprule,
                  late after first line=\\\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-4},
                  late after last line=\\\bottomrule
                ]{table.txt}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii &\csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



That's really a great idea, thanks for your help!

@RedQuark You're welcome!
